# Migration of an application to another server

Tags: jar, weblogic, ear

I am trying to migrate an application A to a Weblogic 10.3.6 Application server running on Oracle Enterprise Linux Operating System. An application B is already residing in that weblogic server. Application A has a GUI with user login feature. However, application B does not. Currently application A and B are interfacing through an MQ.
My queries are:
1. Is it a feasible design to have both applications A & B ears in the same server?
2. If yes, how can they internally communicate?
3. Is there a security breach risk for application B due to user login feature of application A?

Comment: Why do you want them to internally communicate? Is it because the MQ is too slow?

Comment: part of rationalization proposal

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, it is perfectly reasonable to run one or more Ear files on a server. There can be performance issues, and you may need to watch the JVM/Heap memory carefully (one app causing OutOfMemoryError will take down both).

2) Depends how you want them to communicate. The easiest way is probably to use remote lookup. WebLogic provides all lookups for application context etc in a JNDI tree. As long as the methods are exposed to allow remote calls (e.g. @Stateless @Remote annotations in JEE), you can call methods remotely. You can also use other methods such as MDB (message driven beans) if you don't want fast communication, or even Web Services (just bind to the same local server with a different Context root).

3) It depends how you login. If you use weblogic state to check if someone is logged in, then logging in to one application will log you into the other. You would need to look at WebLogic Roles and Policies. Basically set certain users into one Role for one application, and possibly have two different authentication mechanisms setup. Then use @RolesAllowed (or any other ways you fancy) to block access to classes/methods to only the given roles.

If you use your own log in method, I can't see an issue from the user side. Just be careful of what code gets used, and make sure you dont allow remote lookups you arent aware of (ie watch out for methods that could be subject to injection attacks, where malicious code could do a remote lookup to the other application). If you wanted you could still use WebLogic Roles and Policies to block this off anyway.